# Erb condition does not execute statement

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, erb

I have a problem with a form in rails. I'm not able to show input error.
For example if I don't give in input the date (that's not optional), record isn't saved, but form does show anything.

This is my code:

```
FORM
_form.html.erb

<div class ="container">
  <%= puts "Trip is nil: #{@trip.nil?}" %>
  <%= form_with(model: trip) do |f| %>
    <% if trip.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(trip.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this book from being saved:</h2>
      <ul>
        <% trip.errors.full_messages.each do |error| %>
          <li><%= error %></li>
          <% puts "Error: #{error}" %>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :price %>
      <%= f.text_field :price %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :date %>
      <%= date_select :date, start_year: Date.current.year %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :Departure_time %>
      <%= f.text_field :deptime %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :Arrival_time %>
      <%= f.text_field :arrtime %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :From%>
      <%= f.select :from_id, @places_arr %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :To%>
      <%= f.select :to_id, @places_arr %>
    </div>

    <%= link_to 'Non trovi il posto che cerchi? Aggiungilo', new_place_path %>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :vehicle %>
      <%= f.select :vehicle_id, @vehicles_arr %>
    </div>

    <%= link_to 'Vuoi aggiungere un mezzo? Clicca qui', new_vehicle_path %>
  
    <br/>

    <div class="btn btn-primary">
      <%= f.button :submit %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

_form it's a partial called by "new" template

```
<h1>New Trip</h1>
<%= puts "Trip in view: #{@trip}" %>
<%= render 'form', trip: @trip %>

<%= link_to 'Back', trips_path %>
```

This are the last lines of output of terminal when "submit" is pushed:

```
Trip in view: #<Trip:0x00007f61e4c4a548>
Trip is nil: false
Error: Date can't be blank
  Rendered trips/_form.html.erb (Duration: 5.3ms | Allocations: 2831)
  Rendered trips/new.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 6.1ms | Allocations: 3070)
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
  Rendered layouts/_flash.html.erb (Duration: 0.0ms | Allocations: 11)
Completed 200 OK in 41ms (Views: 21.4ms | ActiveRecord: 3.6ms | Allocations: 21083)
```

You can see that if there's an error, lines within "if trip.errors.any?" (in form) are executed, in fact error on terminal are printed, but in html page errors don't appear.
Can someone help me?

For completness I also add controller code:

```
# GET /trips/new
  def new
    @places = Place.all
    @places_arr = []
    for i in (0...@places.length())
      @places_el = [@places[i].name,@places[i].id]
      @places_arr.push(@places_el)
    end

    @vehicles = Vehicle.all
    @vehicles_arr = []
    for i in (0...@vehicles.length())
      @vehicles_el = [@vehicles[i].marca + " " + @vehicles[i].modello, @vehicles[i].id]
      @vehicles_arr.push(@vehicles_el)
    end
    @trip = Trip.new
    @parole = ["ciao","mi","chiamo","Gesualdo"]
    #@parole = []
  end

# POST /trips or /trips.json
  def create
    @places = Place.all
    @places_arr = []
    for i in (0...@places.length())
      @places_el = [@places[i].name,@places[i].id]
      @places_arr.push(@places_el)
    end

    @vehicles = Vehicle.all
    @vehicles_arr = []
    for i in (0...@vehicles.length())
      @vehicles_el = [@vehicles[i].marca + " " + @vehicles[i].modello, @vehicles[i].id]
      @vehicles_arr.push(@vehicles_el)
    end
    @trip = Trip.new(trip_params)

    puts "Nullo? #{@trip.nil?}"

      if @trip.save
        flash[:success] = "Trip successfully saved"
        redirect_to @trip
      else
        render :new
      end
    #end
  end
```

Comment: Did you check the HTML output by viewing the source? My guess it that its a malformed HTML/CSS issues. This code is really ideosyncratic though and full of bugs. `<div class ="container">` is one example.

Comment: Yes, I'm not an expert, so I know my code isn't very good. In HTML source, <div id = "error_explanation"> and its content don't appear. If I push submit looks like page doesn't update

Comment: In console appear two errors.
- The resource from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" was blocked due to mismatch ("application / javascript") of the MIME type (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
- Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'undefined'
webpackMissingModule application.js:18

Comment: UPDATE: I tried to directly save in `new` method of controller a trip with an error. The loaded form show the <div> with the error. I think the problem isn't in html, but reloading page.

Comment: Try using `form_with(model: trip, local: true)` - the method defaulted to `remote: true` until very recently.

Comment: Fantastic, now it works, I didn't know of this options. Thanks